# Search folder for files that contain a server name and extension, then select the last modified file, and grab date in the filename

Tags: loops, vbscript, string-parsing, last-modified, filesystemobject

Trying to use VBScript to do this. I have a folder that has multiple files that include the server name with an extention of .vib. All the files show up as

```
servername.vm-<randomnumber><date>T<time>.vib
```

for example:

```
SERVERNAME.vm-255622016-08-31T040037.vib
```

What I need to do is grab all the files that contain servername*.vib, then find the last modified file of that list, then pull the date from that file. The date is in a xxxx-xx-xx format and always proceeds a T in the file name and seems to be in the same relative place.

So far, I've been able to get pretty close by using [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16288555/loop-through-all-files-in-a-folder-based-on-last-modified-date-descending-ord).

However I'm having trouble with two things, finding files that only contain the servername and getting the date from the file itself.

Here's my code so far:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set list = CreateObject("ADOR.Recordset")
list.Fields.Append "name", 200, 255
list.Fields.Append "date", 7
list.Open

For Each f In fso.GetFolder("J:\Files").Files
  If (fso.GetExtensionName(f) = "vib") And (fso.Contains(ServerName)) Then
    list.AddNew
    list("name").Value = f.Path
    list("date").Value = f.DateLastModified
    list.Update
  End If
Next

list.Sort = "date DESC"
list.MoveFirst
WScript.Echo list("name").Value
list.Close
```

If I remove the `fso.Contains(ServerName)` from the `If` statement then the code runs and I get the latest vib file. I just can't figure out how to test for the servername being contained in the file so I only get files that have the server name in them.

I'm also stuck on how to pull the date from the file itself and can't begin to figure out where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FileSystemObject` objects don't have a `Contains` method. You can test the filename for the server name like this:

```
LCase(Left(f.Name, Len(ServerName))) = LCase(ServerName)
```

However, since you also want to extract the date, a regular expression might be a better approach:

```
Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = ServerName + "\.vm-\d+?(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})T\d{6}\.vib"
```

With that you can test the presence of the server name like this:

```
re.Test(f.Name)
```

and extract the date like this:

```
For Each m In re.Execute(f.Name)
  datestring = m.SubMatches(0)
Next
```

Comment: Awesome, so I got it to work with the information provided for the filename testing, I didn't realize I couldn't do a contains against the FSO.

But I'm having trouble extracting the date with what you've provided. By the end of the original script, I get the file I need and just echo it. I only need the date for this one file but I can't figure out how to use the regular expression to just get the date from the first list item.

Comment: Looks like I was able to get it. I used WScript.Echo re.Execute(list("name").Value).Item(0).Submatches(0)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the final script in case anyone wants it, but I've marked Ansgar's response as the answer.

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set list = CreateObject("ADOR.Recordset")
list.Fields.Append "name", 200, 255
list.Fields.Append "date", 7
list.Open

DIM strServerName
strServerName = "Put_Server_Name_Here"

Set objRe = New RegExp
objRe.IgnoreCase = True
objRe.Pattern = strServerName + "\.vm-\d+?(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})T\d{6}\.vib"

For Each f In fso.GetFolder("J:\Files").Files
  If (fso.GetExtensionName(f) = "vib") AND (objRe.Test(f.Name)) Then
  list.AddNew
  list("name").Value = f.Path
  list("date").Value = f.DateLastModified
  list.Update
  End If
Next

list.Sort = "date DESC"

list.MoveFirst
WScript.Echo list("name").Value
WScript.Echo objRE.Execute(list("name").Value).Item(0).Submatches(0)

list.Close
```